# Unable to load the requested class: PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter

First, I download the PHPExcel in this URL : https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

And I unzip this file and take PHPExcel.php and PHPExcel Folder.

I put them in libraries folder in Codeigniter.

I load the PHPExcel but it returns this message.

```
<?php
        class ExportSample extends REST_Controller{

                public function __construct(){
                parent::__construct();

                    $this->load->database();
                    $this->load->library('PHPExcel');

                }   



    }
?>
```

Error : Unable to load the requested class: PHPExcel

I think put it in libraries and just load the library but maybe it is not.

Is any mistake when I setting it?

Please give me any idea

---

update

```
Error message : require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/appservice/application//third_party/PHPExcel.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
<b>/var/www/html/appservice/application/libraries/Excel.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your path is wrong.

Your library folder should be in:`application/third_party/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php`

After that you need to create one library `excel.php` in `application/libraries/` folder.

Put this code in `excel.php`

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

  require_once APPPATH."/third_party/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php";
  require_once APPPATH."/third_party/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php";

 class Excel extends PHPExcel {
       public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
   }
 }
```

And use this code in your controller `ExportSample.php`:

```
<?php
    class ExportSample extends REST_Controller{

            public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();

               $this->load->database();
               $this->load->library('Excel');
            }   
   }
?>
```

I hope it will work for you!

Comment: Thanks but I have another error occurs. update error message in my question, please check that and help me

Comment: There is no 'application//third_party/PHPExcel.php' on server.If you change your code to something like  require_once "application/third_party/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php".

Comment: Thanks I checked for that and chaged it Thank you for your help

Comment: @PolarisNation, If it's worked then you can give upvote and mark as correct for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
  require_once APPPATH . "/third_party/PHPExcel.php";
```

And clone lib phpExel in application/third_party/

Answer (score 0):

Dont put them in your libraries folder, just put it in your application/third_party folder

it should look like

> ...application/third_party/PHPExcel.php
>
> ...application/third_party/PHPExcel/....

After that create a library called Excel.php or something like that and put it in your library folder

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


require_once APPPATH."/third_party/PHPExcel.php";

class Excel extends PHPExcel    
{
    public function __construct()   
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

> your library folder shoud look like ../application/libraries/Excel.php

And in your Controller

```
class ExportSample extends REST_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->library('Excel');
    }   
}
```

that should pretty much get the job done

Comment: Yes I did put it them into third_party folder and create Excel.php in libraries folder. I just copy that and paste it but it occurs error.
An error message update my question